# How to connect the views functions with two templates in django?

Tags: django, function, templates, view, hyperlink

In one of my views, I have a function that brings some information of some users. Lets say that in the template (Template A) the users are displayed on a table, and each of them has a button. If you click the button, you will be redirected to another template (Template B). What I want to do is that when you click on the button and sends you to the other page, I want to display the information of that user. How do I do that?

Also, the users are random in the first page. I want to associate the button and the user and display the information of that user in the second page (once you click on it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need 2 views, one for `users` and another one for `user_detail`. in the first view template you should create links to the second one.

users view ( checkout [django class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/) ):

```
# import other things like User model

# render shortcut to render template
from django.shortcuts import render

# this is class bassed view
from django.views import View


class UsersView(View):
    # your template path (TemplateA in your case)
    template_name = 'users.html'

    # on get method
    def get(self, request):
        users = User.objects.all()  # you may do something else to get data
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'users': users})
```

and user detail view:

```
class UserDetailView(View):
    template_name = 'user_detail.html'

    def get(self, request, id):
        user = User.objects.get(pk=id)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'user': user})
```

your `urls.py` ( checkout [django URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#example) ):

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UsersView, UserDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', UsersView.as_view(), name='users'),
    path('users/<int:id>/', UserDetailView.as_view(), name='user_detail'),
]
```

finally your `users.html` should have a link to other view:

```
{% for user in users %}
    <p><a href="{% url 'user_detail' user.id %}">{{ user.username }}</a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

we are sending `user.id` as `id` to the `user_detail` view.
checkout [django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/) and also [djngo url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

`user_detail.html` may look like:

```
<ul>
   <li>id: {{ user.id }}</li>
   <li>username: {{ user.username }}</li>
   <li>name: {{ user.first_name }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: glad to hear that!! @add so may you please mark the question as `SOLVED` and `UPVOTE` the question so others can find it useful too? you can find out how to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers